# Display 6 specific PAGES in a Wordpress loop?

Tags: wordpress, loops

How could I diplay six specifics pages by Page ID in a Wordpress loop? So for example I want to display page ID 6, 8, 10, 12, 14 and 16 only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code inside [the_loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop):

```
<?php if ( in_array(get_the_ID(), array(6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16)): ?>
    // continue doing stuff
<?php endif; ?>
```

where 6, 8 etc. are the IDs of the pages you want

Comment: The OP will need to do this on every page template, probably page.php & depending on theme, a fullwidth page template perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing, might be helpful to someone else;

```
<?php 
         $args = array(      
         'post_type' => 'page',              
         'post__in' => array(6,8,10,12,14,16)   
             );
   query_posts($args);  
?>

<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 // thumbnail, title etc..
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks anyway guys

Comment: Thanks for this, worked a treat. I also needed to control the exact order rather than just ascending or descending. If you add "'orderby' => 'post__in'" it will then show the pages in the order of the array.